# PHP XmlHttpRequest error with simple to-do list

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Being new to PHP and ajax XmlHttpRequest calls altogether, I am struggling to figure out what is wrong with my code. Gone through the documentation but it seems I'm struggling to put the db row `names` into an array. I ideally want to asynchronously display an `innerHTML` below the input to indicate whether the item is in db or not. Right now it is showing 'undefined' as seen below until I type the last item in the db. it's only responding to the last item in the db meaning there's probably an issue with my loop. Any help is welcome.

[image]

[image]

**index.php**

```
<?php 
include 'db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="js/todo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

    </script>


</head>
<body onload="process()">
    <div class="list">
        <h1 class="header">My To Do</h1>
        <form>
            <ul class="items">
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY items.id ASC";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<li><input type='checkbox' /><label>";
                        echo $row['name'];
                        echo "</label></li><br>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "There are no to-dos!";
                }

                echo "<br/><br/>";
                echo "<li><input type='checkbox' /><label>Mark all as completed</label></li>";
            ?>
            </ul><br />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
        <form class="item-add" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter new item" class="input" autocomplete="off" required>
            <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Add Item">
            <div id="status"></div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

**item.php**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY items.id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $itemArray = array();

    $rowNum = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //is this the correct way to add db items to an array?
    if($rowNum > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $rowNum; $x++) {

                $itemArray[$x] = $row['name'];  
            }

        }

    } else {
        echo "There are no to-dos!";
    }

    $entry   = $_GET['name'];
    if(in_array($entry, $itemArray))
        echo 'Item ' .$entry. ' already exists! Please enter a new item...';
    elseif ($name == '') 
        echo "Please enter an item...";
    else {
        //code for insertion
            echo "Successfully Inserted";

    }

echo '</response>';

?>
```

**item.js**

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp) {
        alert("cant create that object hoss");
    } else {
        return xmlHttp;
    }

}

function process() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
        name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "item.php?name="+name, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;

        xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            console.log(xmlResponse.documentElement);
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 
            '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is printed in `console.log(xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data)`

Comment: @Niladri a looping `<response></response>` tag from `item.php` echoing "Please enter an item". When I enter 'ssd' in the field, it loops with the correct response as well e.g ` 'Item ssd' already exists! Please enter a new item...';`

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name` is not defined in your PHP file , Shouldnt it be `$entry` that you are checking in the `elseif` condition below

```
$entry   = $_GET['name'];
if(in_array($entry, $itemArray))
    echo 'Item ' .$entry. ' already exists! Please enter a new item...';
elseif ($entry == '') 
    echo "Please enter an item...";
else {
    //code for insertion
        echo "Successfully Inserted";

}
```

also the correct way to assign a DB column to an array should be like below .

```
if($rowNum > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $itemArray[] = $row['name'];  
        }

    } else {
        echo "There are no to-dos!";
    }
```

Comment: In the `elseif`. Nice catch.

Comment: @Styx updated my answer , perhaps the other values are not even pushed to array

Comment: oh yes thanks for pointing that out. Partly fixed now. It still does not indicate for example that 'Football' already exists in the db when i type it in the field.

Comment: @colin_dev256 Perhaps, you're searching `football` while in your DB there is `Football`

Comment: Yes now it works. I was very sure I was doing the array insertion wrongly. Thanks guys.. Big time Java mind-set. Still struggling with php syntax.

Comment: @colin_dev256 be sure in_array() is case sensitive for string values

Comment: which would you recommend i use?

Comment: @colin_dev256 in_array() is fine if you can handle the case

Comment: i'd prefer a non case-sensitive call if there's one